# Greasemonkey - Let script wait after reaching i count and continue afterwards

Tags: javascript, tags, comments, greasemonkey

I am still kinda new to the whole coding thing and also this website.

I have a script (not fully written by me, as I said, I am still new to coding) which automatically tags people from a list in a comment section. Currently I have 3 separate scrips, as I can only make 70 comments before I have to wait for about an hour.

What I am trying to do, is to set it up so it runs the script fully automated and waits 60 minutes after every 70 comments, and will repeat if needed and continue until the list is done.

What I do know is that "i" is used as variable to count here. But I do not know how I can read the variable to make the script wait for 60 minutes every 70 steps, so that it stops at 70 for one hour and at 140 and at 210 and so on.

```js
var list1 = [
   "tag1 tag2 tag3",
   "tag4 tag5 tag6",
   "tag7 tag8 tag9",
   "tag10 tag11 tag12",
   "and so on...",
   
 ];

 
var i = 1;

window.onkeydown = function(keyPressed){
   
  if(keyPressed.keyCode == 121){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("post-text-area")[0].value = "Count 1" + "/" + list1.length + "\n"+ list1[0];
    document.getElementsByClassName("cmnt-btn")[0].click();
    
   if(list1.length>1){
var repeat1 = setInterval(function start(){
if(i == list1.length-1){
    clearInterval(repeat1);
}
document.getElementsByClassName("reply")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("post-text-area")[1].value = "Count " + (i+1) + "/" + list1.length + "\n" + list1[i];
document.getElementsByClassName("cmnt-btn")[1].click(); 
i++;
  },2000);i=1;}}
    
};
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question with Java, when your question is about Javascript? They are not the same language.

Comment: Very likely because, as my very first sentence says: "I am still kinda new to the whole coding thing", thanks for correcting me though.